# Nonlinear maps as a set of linear maps?

Tags: functions

I am wondering if a nonlinear map can be considered like a set of linear maps, with a different linear map for each element in the domain. And a linear map would then be the case where the offsets and scales are the same over the whole domain.

Or does nonlinear map have more connotations to it?

Comment: It is not at all clear how a non linear map can be viewed as a collection of linear maps.

Comment: For each input, it would map a ordered list of vectors to an ordered list of vectors (i.e. be linear). But- it would map them in different ways for each input (i.e. ordered list of vectors)

Comment: (Taken individually, you could try to apply the to different inputs, but it would possibly give the 'wrong' result)

Comment: (Unless you allow the codomain to vary with the inputs as well, but let's not get that crazy in this question unless we need to).